# Have Prettier remove <space> after async keyword

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, prettier

I am working on a VueJs project and i use eslint and Prettier in VSCode. The problem that i am having is that eslint doesnt want a space after the `async` keyword nut Prettier does. So when `vue-cli-service serve` builds the source it complains that prettier wants a space after async, if i add it manually then eslint throws errors that it doesnt want a space after async.

Prettier formats:

```
export const myFunction = async (...args) => {};
```

Eslint expects:

```
export const myFunction = async(...args) => {};
```

I want to tell Prettier to NOT have a space after the async keyword OR tell eslint to ignore the space after the async keyword, any suggestions?

Comment: In case this matters, the style you're enforcing is not conventional by any means. You don't write `asyncfunction() {}` but `async function() {}`, why should an arrow be treated differently. The problem with it is that `async(...args)` can be read as 'we call a function named async with spread args' (it's not uncommon because async is not reserved keyword), and then there's `=>` that suggests that it was misread.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just found a forum question with an answer that fixed my problem. In the `.eslintrc.js` file you can add a rule as follows:

```
'space-before-function-paren': [
      'error',
      {
        anonymous: 'never',
        named: 'never',
        asyncArrow: 'always'
      }
    ]
```

The asyncArrow: '**always**' rule fixed the compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

For Prettier not to conflict with ESLint, all ESLint's formatting-related rules should be disabled. See https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html